# What data structure is necessary for survival analysis?

Tags: survival, dataset

I'm relatively new to survival analysis and try to get my data in the right shape.

I have two tables both concerning the observed individuals. If I just would use one of the tables, I would have continuous information on each individual without any overlapping periods.

As I however also need the information stored in the other table, it is necessary to merge the two tables. But then the episodes will be overlapping in some cases.

I give you an example as illustration:

Table 1:

```
ID: 1
start: 2000-01-01
end: 2002-12-31
state: A
```

Table 2:

```
ID: 1
start: 2002-01-01
end: 2002-04-15
state: Z
```

To do survival analysis (in Stata or R) does it matter if there are overlaps?

If it does, do you have any suggestions on how to remove the overlaps?

Comment: Could you indicate what information is required from Table 2 (or are there multiple outcomes?), and what would be the general form of your survival model?

Comment: I want to do a parametric model with time varying covariats. The subject is how long people stay in certain jobs related to some different parameters.

In table 1 I have data concerning the person, the firm, and the contract. In table 2 there is information concerning episodes the person is unemployed. Unfortunately a person can take like "small jobs" while being unemployed. Therefor the data is overlapping sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that by "parametric model" the OP means *fully* parametric, then this sounds like a question about the appropriate data structure for discrete time survival analysis (aka discrete time event history) models such as logit (1), probit (2), or complimentary log-log (3) hazard models, then the appropriate answer is that the data typically need to be structured in a *person-period* format.

1. $h_{t} = \frac{e^{\mathbf{BX}}}{1 + e^{\mathbf{BX}}}$
2. $h_{t} = \Phi(\mathbf{BX})$
3. $h_{t} = 1 - e^{-e^{\mathbf{BX}}}$

where $\mathbf{BX}$ are the parameters and predictors in the model. Often discrete time survival analysis models will include *dummy variables* for each time period (see below) and also often include time period itself, or even functions of it, as a variable.

Here's what a person-period data set looks like:

```
ID period y x1 x2 x3 t1 t2 t3 . . . tT
1  1      0 1  3  12 1  0  0  . . . 0
1  2      0 1  0  12 0  1  0  . . . 0
1  3      1 1  9  12 0  0  1  . . . 0
2  1      0 0  4  6  1  0  0  . . . 0
3  1      0 1  0  17 1  0  0  . . . 0
3  2      0 1  3  17 0  1  0  . . . 0
3  3      0 1  3  17 0  0  1  . . . 0
etc.
```

First of all notice both `ID` and `period` which define the hierarchical period of observation nested in person structure of these data. Also notice that `x2` is *time varying* (i.e. within the same individual it can take different values in different periods), and that `x1` and `x3` are static; understand that the model is agnostic as to whether predictors are time-varying or static. Finally examine the relationship between period and the indicator variables for time/period (i.e. `t1` through `tT`).

Often times you will receive data in a *person-time* format such as this:

```
ID TimeToEvent Censored x1 x2t1 x2t2 . . . x2tT x3,
```

and will need to transform the data appropriately. Here `TimeToEvent` measures how many periods each subject was observed while in the study, and `Censored` indicates whether or not the subject left the study *without experiencing the event* (i.e. whether that subject was *right censored*). In your data `TimeToEvent` probably equals `end` - `start`, and `Censored` is certainly some function of `state`.

There are often tools available for transforming data such as these. For example, in Stata, see `net describe dthaz, from(http://alexisdinno.com/stata)`